# Confuse about how font-icon work

Tags: css, font-awesome

I found which make the font-awesome class worked is the pseudo element in the target element. For example, if I want an camera icon, I just insert an pseudo element in the target element with content `\f083`:

```
h1:before {
    content: '\f083';
}
```

But my confuse is, if I directly set the `\f083` as some element's content like `<span>\f083</span>`, the element doesn't doesn't appear an icon.

So how font-icon exactly work? Why the content only work in pseudo element?

Comment: \f083 is not the right encode for html. You need something like  `&#xf083;`

Comment: Agree with @timo. Another thing is the good practice of writing custom contents in your css. Is better if you use the font-awesome default classes. If you want a camera icon, just write `<inline-tag class="fa fa-camera"></inline-tag>` where `inline-tag` is the same as `a`,`i`,`span`, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In CSS**, string literals like `'\f083'` are escape sequences for characters. In other words, `\f083` *means* the single Unicode character U+F083 (which is a private use area character, it has no default meaning).

HTML does not follow those same escape sequence codes. "\f083" in HTML simply means "\f083". The equivalent escape sequence in HTML would be `&#xf083;`.

In both CSS and HTML you *could* simply write the actual character itself: "". Though since it's an unallocated character by default, it either won't show up in your editor, or display as a square or something else, and it'll also be subject to the encoding of the file, which makes it a bit harder to work with.